# Disappearing after mouse out menu with jQuery/WordPress

Tags: jquery

i have altered the script for jQuery menu in wordpress, and everything works fine except the menu item is not removing itself after mouse out.
It remains over another selected menu item. My question is - if anyone can help mw with adding mouse out effect on this menu?
here is the code

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

```
jQuery("#nav ul.sub-menu").hide();

jQuery('li:has(ul.sub-menu)').children('a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();     
    jQuery(this).parent('li').find('ul:first').fadeToggle(1000);

});

var currentMenuItem = jQuery('.current-menu-item');
var currentMenuItemText = currentMenuItem.text();
currentMenuItem.remove('a');
currentMenuItem.text(currentMenuItemText);
jQuery('.current-menu-item').parent('ul:first').show();


});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your menu is set to hide when you click again. To use the mouseout to hide it, it should look like:

```
jQuery('li:has(ul.sub-menu)').children('a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();     
    jQuery(this).parent('li').find('ul:first').fadeIn(1000);
}).mouseout(function(){
    jQuery(this).parent('li').find('ul:first').fadeOut(1000);
});
```

Comment: Hi, the menu consists of 3 parts: Portfolio | Item | gallery1 | Item 2| gallery1 now, the Item and galley are just fading out (no matter if you hold your mouse over it), and Item 2 gallery is still overlapping with Item1 if selected. link to the menu: http://www.majahrastinski.com/lang/hr/transforma/
any hints if possible? i'd appreciate it

Comment: in fact, the only problem is that the 3rd menu category  is not dissapearing after mouse.out. I would appreciate some help. Thank you

Comment: @zuul78 can you post a link to the menu?

Comment: Fade out is working, but the menu doesnt expand normally with refreshed menu content. Is it possible to set the menu to hide when mouse out instead of click?